# Stock behaviour probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I found this question in a financial mathematics course exam, could anyone please help with a solution and some explanation? Thanks in advance :)

> A stock has beta of $2.0$ and stock specific daily volatility of $0.02$.
>   Suppose that yesterday’s closing price was $100$ and today the market
>   goes up by $1$%. What’s the probability of today’s closing price being
>   at least $103$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expectation of the stock price is $100*(1+2*0.01)=102$

standard deviation is $2\%$, which is $2$

$103$ is $0.5$ standard deviation away,

$1-N(0.5)=31\%$

Comment: What is the quantity $N(0.5)$? If it is the normal distribution, how have you determined the parameters?
My understanding of the stock market is quite minimalistic, could you point me in the right direction of the maths knowledge required to answer these types of questions? Many thanks

Comment: Having randomly stumbled upon this answer after so many years, I would argue that there's something not fully correct in the reasoning above, as the answer implicitly stipulates that the prices (!) are normally distributed. While the numerical result might be the same (to be confirmed), a standard assumption is that it is rather the returns that follow some (here: normal) distribution.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming normality, vola being specified as standard deviation and assuming a risk free rate (r_risk_free) of zero the following reasoning could be applied:

1) From CAPM we see that the expected return of the stock (E(r)=r_risk_free+beta*(r_market-r_risk_free) here E(r)=0+2.0*.01=0.02

2) From a casual definition of beta we know that it relates stock specific vola to market vola (sd_stock_total=beta*sd_stock_specific) here sd_stock_total=2*0.02=.04

3) Since we have data on returns only, we transfer the value of interest (103) into returns space which is r_of_interest=(103-100)/100=0.03

4) Now we are looking for the probability that the return of interest occurs (P(x>=0.03)) given the probability distribution defined as N(0.02,0.04) or written differently P(x>=0.03)~N(0.02,0.04)

5) In R you could write 1-(pnorm(.03,mean=.02,sd=.04)) where 1-pnorm(...) is necessary because pnorm() returns P(X<=x) of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) and you are interested in P(x>=0.03) - [more pnorm() hints](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/old/5101/rlook.html).